# Different Behaviors Digesting \csname x\endcsname and Digesting \x (expansion issue)

Tags: tex-core, expansion, optional-arguments, parsing

This question has been significantly EDITED, as I learned more of the problem.

---

If I was good, I would be able to create macros with multiple optional arguments, but not only can't I, but in this case, I'm trying to adapt an existing structure.  I wrote the `boxhandler` package to be able to tune figure/table captions layouts (in particular, to a strange style my organization has).  That aside, the syntax for a figure is

```
\bxfigure[htbp]{caption}{figure content}
```

Someone has requested the ability to use `\caption`'s optional argument, which this present structure does not allow.  So I thought I could provide a syntax that works with the above syntax or with the following

```
\bxfigure[htbp]{[LOF caption]full caption}{figure content}
```

The code I thought would have done that is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bx@caption[1]{%
\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[#1]\relax%
}

\def\optcaption[#1]#2\relax{%
\ifstrempty{#2}{\caption{#1}}{\caption[\@gobble#1]{\striptrailingbracket#2}}}
%\ifstrempty{#2}{Full caption is \fbox{#1}}
%  {LOF caption is \fbox{\@gobble#1} Full caption is \fbox{\striptrailingbracket#2}}}

\def\striptrailingbracket#1]{#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

%\def\x{my caption}
%\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[\x]\relax

\def\x{[LOF caption]my caption}
%\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[\x]\relax

\bxfigure[h]{my caption}{\fbox{TEXT}}
\bxfigure[h]{[LOF caption]my caption}{\fbox{TEXT}}
\bxfigure[h]{\x}{\fbox{TEXT}}
%\optcaption[[LOF caption]my caption]\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]

but as you see, the `\optcaption` parser does not extract the bracketed content from the argument, and always thinks the `#1` argument of `\def\optcaption[#1]#2\relax{}` is without a right bracket.

To make the problem simpler, I studied the behavior of `\optcaption` specifically, apart from including it in `\bxfigure`.  And here,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bx@caption[1]{%
\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[#1]\relax%
}

\def\optcaption[#1]#2\relax{%
%\ifstrempty{#2}{\caption{#1}}{\caption[\@gobble#1]{\striptrailingbracket#2}}}
\ifstrempty{#2}{Full caption is \fbox{#1}}
  {LOF caption is \fbox{\@gobble#1} Full caption is \fbox{\striptrailingbracket#2}}}

\def\striptrailingbracket#1]{#1}
\begin{document}

All of these work...\par
\bx@caption{[LOF caption]my caption}\par
\def\x{my caption}
\bx@caption{\x}\par
\def\x{[LOF caption]my caption}\par
\bx@caption{\x}\par
~\\The following does not work (and boxhandler passes the caption via a 
csname; this is the root of the problem)\par
\bx@caption{\csname x\endcsname}\par
~\\This fixes it, but it requires me to change the code that calls bx@caption\par
\expandafter\bx@caption\expandafter{\csname x\endcsname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

we see that it is able to detect the `]` and extract the optional argument, even when that argument is passed by way of a macro `\x`, but not when it is passed as `\csname x\endcsname`.

---

So I suppose I can go back and change the `boxhandler` calls to `\bx@caption` to pre-expand the `\csname` as I did in my last example (see my answer below).

**But if anyone can rewrite `\bx@caption` to be able to properly digest a `\csname` argument (without patching `\ReciteFigure`), I will accept that answer.**

Comment: If it doesn't need to be plain tex, I would recommend using [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and a syntax which is more `LaTeX` "standard" style with two optional parameters: `\bxfigure[htbp][LOF caption]{full caption}{figure content}`.  Of course this would need to be able to handle usage such as `\bxfigure[][LOF caption]{full caption}{figure content}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I may consider that possibility in the final evaluation, but am still interested in finding out why `#1` is characteristically different than `\x`.  And it certainly doesn't need to be plain tex.

Comment: `#1` will contain the first argument supplied. `\x` may be passed as-is, a single token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX optional arguments are a delimited argument defined via `\def\foo[#1]{...}` (unless you define them via latex3 declarations) so `[]` are *not* matched and the argument ends at the first `]`

```
\optcaption[[LOF caption]my caption]\relax
```

`#1` is `[LOF caption`

To use `[]` in an optional argument you need

```
 \optcaption[{[LOF caption]my caption}]\relax
```

The LaTeX3 declarations define the command to use a slower, more careful way of picking up the optional argument that does match `[]`.

It is not clear what

```
\caption[\@gobble#1]
```

is intended to do but it almost certainly does the wrong thing.

If `#1` is  `[LOF caption]full caption`  then the above is

```
\caption[\@gobble[LOF caption]full caption]
```

so the optional argument of `\caption` is `\@gobble[LOF caption`  and `\@gobble` will gobble the `[` however the following mandatory argument of `\caption` is then just `f`.  and `ull caption]` are left as trailing tokens that do whatever they do.

---

In your edited question you need to expand twice, or simpler expand until there is an unexpandable token before looking for `[` so

```
\renewcommand\bx@caption[1]{%
\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[\romannumeral-`x#1]\relax%
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is actually more complex than I present it above, and that the guts of `boxhandler` may come into play, in which case I should probably delete the question.  In particular, `\bxfigure[h]{{[LOF caption]my caption}}{\fbox{TEXT}}` still does not work, while `\bx@caption{\x}` does work.  That leads me to believe the issue is in the guts of `boxhandler`, in the way that the caption argument is stored and later recalled.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\x` is a single token which you pass from internal macro to another as a token, but `#1` is not a token it is a placeholder for the tokens passed in and unless you brace it as `{#1}` when passing to an internal macro that macro will get _the first token_ (only) of the original argument, not the whole of `#1`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes see update

Comment: `\@gobble#1` eats the leading `[` from an argument of the form `[LOF caption`.  See my update.  Upon further digging, I recall that `boxhandler` provides the caption in a `\csname x\endcsname` manner, which I now believe is the root of the problem.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it does,  but it makes the main caption just be a single letter. I added some code following your edit to the question

Comment: See alternate solution provided, using my provided macros, but now with an `xpatch`.

Comment: The old `\romannumeral` trick, eh?

Answer (score 2):

Well, once I determined the problem was with digesting a `\csname` that was passed to `\bx@caption`, I determined that one solution was to patch `boxhandler` to pre-expand the argument that was being passed.  Using the definitions in my first example, and patching the calls to `\bx@caption` took care of it.

If anyone else can solve this problem without resorting to `xpatch`, I will accept that answer.

---

David's edit of using the `\romannumeral` trick,

```
\renewcommand\bx@caption[1]{%
\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[\romannumeral-`x#1]\relax%
}
```

instead of what I have in this answer, alleviates the need for `xpatch`, so he gets the points!  Thank you, David.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ReciteFigure}% <cmd>
  {\bx@caption}% <search>
  {\expandafter\bx@caption\expandafter}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\xpatchcmd{\ReciteTable}% <cmd>
  {\bx@caption}% <search>
  {\expandafter\bx@caption\expandafter}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\renewcommand\bx@caption[1]{%
\expandafter\optcaption\expandafter[#1]\relax%
}

\def\optcaption[#1]#2\relax{%
\ifstrempty{#2}{\caption{#1}}{\caption[\@gobble#1]{\striptrailingbracket#2}}}

\def\striptrailingbracket#1]{#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\bxfigure[ht]{my caption}{\fbox{TEXT}}
\bxfigure[ht]{[LOF caption]my caption}{\fbox{TEXT}}
\end{document}
```

[image]